# Generating dynamic check box using cakephp, how do i handle and when should i submit form?

Tags: cakephp

i am generating dynamic multiple checkbox, how  should i generate that and how should i manage that in cakephp?

Answer (score 3):

The checkboxes should look like this:

```
<input name="data[ModelName][ModelName][]" value="x" id="ModelNameModeNamex" /> your Text
```

I created a helper for this, that renders the checkboxes in a table. It was derived from [this helper](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/create-multiple-checkboxes-instead-of-a-multiple-select-in-your-views)

---

**EDIT**
The data will be submitted as an array, that the CakeMagic can deal with. For the default example Post <-habtm-> Tag an input field in the post-view should be

```
<input name="data[Tag][Tag][]" value="4" id="TagTag4" /> myTagName
```

when submitting the data and doing a save in the PostsController, Cake will also save the habtm association in the `posts_tags` table. If you are interested how exactely the data looks, simply place `debug($this->data);` in the PostsController

---

also, 2 comments:

1. If you would like some help, please put some effort in formulating the question
2. It might help if you would accept an answer once in a while

Comment: if all name check box name and id are same then how i get value of array when i submit form plz help me

Answer (score 0):

Only the name attribute is really important, it decides how the data will be posted back.  Getting the value of the array should be doable through `$this->data` or `$this->params`.